# Fail to return a derived class pointer when overriding a virtual method

Tags: c++, g++

This question is about overriding a virtual method in a derived class with a different return type.
For the following code:

```
class father {
public:
  virtual father* ref() { return this; }
};

class child : public father {
  virtual child* ref() { return this; }
};
```

When I try to get a pointer directly, g++ (F15, g++4.5) reports "invalid conversion from father to child"

```
child m_child;
father* pf = &m_child;
child* pc = pf->ref();
```

I understand the ref() method in the child class is used and this is probably just a compile time type mismatch.

However, is there any way to do it without explicitly use a type cast?

Extra description:
I understand the reason why compiler report this error. What I need is something out of the box which can access the data in derived object without explicitly convert a pointer.

The father class is used to put different derived child objects into lists or vectors, so when an item is fetch from the list or vector, there is no way to tell which child class it is belong to.

I have internal method to record and check the child class type. But I dont want to explicitly convert the pointer.

For example, I would like to do something like this:

```
// assuming pf is pointer pointed to an item fetch from a vector
switch(fp->get_type()) {
case child_type1: fp->ref()->list1.push(data); break;
case child_type2: fp->ref()->list2.push(data); break;
case child_type3: fp->ref()->list3.push(data); break;
}
```

Right now, I need to explicitly declare a new variable or explicitly convert fp to the proper type in each case and each time I need to access a data in derived classes, which are tedious and confusing.

What I expect are: may be some boost libraries can do similar things in another way which I dont know yet, or may be the c++11 standard allows it but a special compiling parameter needs to be set?

Comment: I think I understand it perfectly well why the compiler reports a type mismatch. What I need is not a explanation about what happens here. I need something out of the box.  To further explain it, pls see the extra description added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer is "no".

You've lost the extra information (`child*` rather than `father*`) about  `ref` when you threw away `m_child`s type information, by storing it as pointer to base (`pf`).

One reason why it will never be possible without a cast is this example:

```
class father {
public:
  virtual father* ref() { return this; }
};

class childA : public father {
  virtual childA* ref() { return this; }
};

class childB : public father {
  virtual childB* ref() { return this; }
};

void should_never_compile(int i)
{
   childA a;
   childB b;
   father pf;
   if( i ) { pf=&a; }
   else { pf=&b; }

   // This is evil and will not compile
   childA * pa = pf->ref();

   //But this is OK:
   childA * pa = dynamic_cast<childA*>(pf->ref() );
}
```

If you really want to make this doable without the dynamic cast you can just hide the dynamic cast (but it scares me a little)

```
class father {
public:
  virtual father* ref() { return this; }
  template<typename T> T* as() { return dynamic_cast<T*>(ref()); }
};

child m_child;
father* pf = &m_child;
child* pc = pf->as<child>();
```

Comment: Thanks, you provide me something looks better!

Answer (score 1):

Your function does what you expect and what you tell it to. The line

```
child* pc = pf->ref();
```

is the problem. You call the function "ref()" on a pointer-to-father, which returns (by type) a father *. You assign this - without conversions - to a child *. The implementation of that function returns a child *, but *from where you call it that information is not known* as you only know that it's a father *. The return type is therefore a father * (as indicated in the class father), and you assign that without conversion to a child *. You **can** do:

```
child *pc = m_child.ref();
father *pf = m_child.ref();
father *pf2 = pf->ref();
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that in the call `pf->ref()`, the type of `ref` is: `father* (father::*)()`.

That is, `ref` is resolved *statically* to be a `virtual` method with a given signature. And this signature indicates that it returns a `father*`.

Thus:

```
int main() {
  father f;
  father* pf = &f;

  child c;
  child* pc = &c;

  child* xf = pf->ref(); // compile-time failure
  child* xc = pc->ref(); // okay
}
```

The problem is that, in general, starting from a `father*` you cannot know whether or not you will get a `child*`, it depends on the dynamic type of the instance. So the compiler assumes the worst case: it must at least be `father`.